# undified variable while its defined laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

hi i have an script that i am adding some values into an array turn it into object and then return it like below:

```
 if (ProductType::hasVariants($product->type)) {
//            $variantImage = $product->variants->first()->images->first()->path ?? null;
            foreach ($product->variants as $variant) {
                if (count($variant->images)) {
                    $variantImage[] = $variant->images->first() ?? null;
                    $final_variants = collect($variantImage);

                }
            }
        }
      //  dd($final_variants); if i dd this here it has value
        return [
            'name' => $product->name,
            'slug' => $product->url_key,
            'description' => $product->description,
            'shortDescription' => $product->short_description,
            'variantsHtml' => view('shop::products.variants', ['final_variants' => $final_variants])->render(),  ];
```

As you see above if i dd `final_variants` it has value but when i try to return it it gives me this error:

```
Undefined variable: final_variants
and its on this line :
'variantsHtml' => view('shop::products.variants', ['final_variants' => $final_variants])->render(),
```

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: Could it be that sometimes `$product->variants`  is empty, so the loop doesn't happen at all?

Comment: i thinked that but when i dd the variable it has value in it i see it

Comment: Set `$final_variants = null` before the `if (ProductType::hasVariants($product->type)) {` condition. Your `dd($final_variants)` must show `null` on occasion? Any case, you should not get an undefined variable error any longer.